# Unable to render dynamic data list Vue TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to render list of an interface that is dynamically updated by the script in the component.

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { defineProps, resolveDirective } from 'vue';
import XLSX from 'xlsx'
import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue';
import { DataInterface } from '@/types'


export default defineComponent({ 
    data() {
      return {
        testData: {data: "This is Data", value: "2"} as DataInterface,
        dataList: [] as DataInterface[] 
      }
    },

    methods: {
    generateSudoData() {
        this.outlierList = [this.DataInterface, this.DataInterface];
        this.calculateLimit();
    },
    calculateLimit() {
        for (const data of this.dataList) {
            data.value += 2;
        }
    }
  },
});
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <label class="file-reader">
    <input type="file" @change="generateSudoData">
    <li v-for="(data, x) in dataList" :key="x">
      <h3>{{data.Value}}</h3>
    </li>
  </label>
</template>
```

I keep getting this warning
[Vue warn]: Property "dataList" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

Comment: You haven't declared `outlierList` upfront as a `data` property. You're accessing it from the render function (i.e. in the template somewhere either directly or indirectly) before it has been defined.

Comment: I updated the data component as such:

data() {
const dataList: testData[] = [{data: "This is Data", value: 2}]
return dataList;}

Still getting the same error

Comment: What is the difference between `outlierList` and `dataList`? Should they be the same thing?

Comment: Sorry my bad they are the same